# How to make R datatables column width dependant on cell content width?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I know you can use options to adjust width by hand. Something along the lines:

```
DT::datatable(mtcars,
              options = list(
                  autoWidth = TRUE,
                  columnDefs = list(list(width = '70px', 
                                         targets = which(colnames(mtcars) %in% c("gear"))),
                                    list(width = '100px', 
                                         targets = which(colnames(mtcars) %in% c("disp", "hp")))
                  )
              )
)
```

I see no way to adjust the column width to fit content, without hardcoded values. I found a `datatables` function [columns.adjust()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) which theoretically re-adjusts column width to input, but how to use it in R / R shiny?

MRE:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(mtcars,
                options = list(
                    autoWidth = TRUE, # here we set fixed width. how to set depending on input?
                    columnDefs = list(list(width = '70px', 
                                           targets = which(colnames(mtcars) %in% c("gear"))),
                                      list(width = '100px', 
                                         targets = which(colnames(mtcars) %in% c("disp", "hp")))
                    )
                )
  )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The problem is that DT sets the width of their tables to 100% and you can't set `with = "auto"` because the `datatable()` parameter only accepts pixels according to the documentation. The only way I've found to change with to auto is to override the css style for the dataTable css class. You and add a tag like this `tags$style("table.dataTable {width:auto}")`  or just add the instruction in a separate css file. This will let the table adjust to its contents.

Comment: @guasi you have to set `autoWidth = TRUE` to be able to use width in `columnDefs`, it says it is a known bug in the DT documentation. I'll try your approach with css

Comment: I added `width: auto;` to a `table.dataTable` element in browser inspector, and it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: You have to set it to the table, not any of the div wrappers. I tested it with a table with a few columns and the table shrinks to it's contents. I won't post a solution because this is a hack, not a real solution. Some of the wrappers have width:100% hard coded inline, not even through a css class, so everything is being forced to take the available space. I tried setting width to auto for entire table and different columns through JS options, but none took.

Comment: Might be because I am using a `shinydashboard` and a `shinyBS` to render table in a collapsible that it is not working for me..